# Prisma extend schema to include external data

Tags: javascript, typescript, orm, prisma

I'm contemplating using Prisma to provide a service that aggregates data from a database with some data from an external API. I need to use the response from a database query to build the request to the API, then have some of the fields returned from the API as additional columns in the data.

I see that Prisma now supports Prisma Client extensions which seems like it could be part of the solution, however I can't find any documentation or examples that cover this use case.

Is Prisma the right solution here ?

---

I was looking at the Prisma Client extensions, computed field example, but can't get it to work when calling an async function. e.g.

```
import { Prisma, PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

async function asynctest() {
  return "hello there"
}

const prisma = new PrismaClient()
  .$extends({
    result: {
      user: {
        fullName: {
          needs: { firstName: true, lastName: true },
          compute(user) {
            return `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`;
          },
        },
      },
    },
  })
  .$extends({
    result: {
      user: {
        displayName: {
          needs: { fullName: true, email: true },
          async compute(user) {
            //var data = ""
            //getCert().then((data: any)=>{return `${user.fullName} <${user.email}>` + data})
            return `${user.fullName} <${user.email}>` + await asynctest();
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });

async function main() {
  const users = await prisma.user.findMany({ take: 5 });

  for (const user of users) {
    console.info(`- ${user.displayName}`);
  }
}

main()
  .then(async () => {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  })
  .catch(async (e) => {
    console.error(e);
    await prisma.$disconnect();
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If the additional column values are computed from the data that you fetch from the database then you can use computed fields example as mentioned in this Prisma Client Extensions Repository: https://github.com/prisma/prisma-client-extensions

Comment: Any idea if you can call an async function using the Prisma Client Extensions. I was looking at the computed field example but can't seem to make that work. e.g.

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know

Comment: Thanks that would be much appreciated - I’ve spent quite some time on it, and can’t figure it out

Comment: Did you have any luck with this ?

Comment: There is an alternative, see this link, seems like prisma does not support promise on computed
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/18300